# How to signout from Sharepoint mobile page?

Tags: 2010, mobile

I have developed a Sharepoint 2010 site for mobile devices. How do I logout from the site. I can redirect the user to _layouts\Signout.aspx?mobile=1 on clicking my custom logout button. But I am not redirected to the mobile version of signout page. Is there any mobile version of the signout page available(mbllogout.aspx is not working for me) or do I have to write custom code. If so please guide me to some references. By the way I am using Windows authentication.

Thank You.